# Bitset and signed values

Tags: c++, binary, signed, bitset

I am using `std::bitset` to convert a decimal value to its binary representation, but I am not sure if `bitset` handles signed values or not.

For example, `bitset<10>(5)` gives you `0000000101`. But what if its `bitset<10>(-5)`?

Here is my code in specific:

```
while (getline(ss, token, ',')){
    ss.ignore();
    myString.push_back(token);
}
myString[0].erase(0, 1);
myString[1].erase(0, 1);
rt = bitset<7>(stoi(myString[0])).to_string();
ra = bitset<7>(stoi(myString[1])).to_string();
i10 = bitset<10>(stoi(myString[2])).to_string();
```

and the `i10` should be signed. Will my current code handle signed values? myString will hold the decimal representation that is input by a user, but i need to do some concatenating and writing to a file so im converting to strings for ease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bitset` doesn't handle signed-ness itself. The constructor you're calling takes an `unsigned` integer. From [bitset.cons]:

> ```
> constexpr bitset(unsigned long long val) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Constructs an object of class `bitset<N>`, initializing the first `M` bit positions to the corresponding
>   bit values in val. `M` is the smaller of `N` and the number of bits in the value representation (3.9) of
>   unsigned long long. If `M < N`, the remaining bit positions are initialized to zero.

So if you call it with `-5`, that gets converted to `unsigned long long` as `0xfffffffffffffffb`. The bottom 10 bits of that are `0x3fb`, which is the set you get. But it's unsigned. Both conversion functions give you back an unsigned value (from [bitset.members]):

```
unsigned long to_ulong() const;
unsigned long long to_ullong() const;
```

All of which is to say - a `bitset` is a set of bits. It doesn't have a sign. The first bit isn't special - it's just another bit.

Answer (score 1):

Bitset will return the binary representation. Since negative numbers are stored using the two's complement, you will get their representation in the twos complement. For example:

```
cout << bitset<12>(-5).to_string();
// Prints 111111111011
```

Comment: Negative numbers are not necessarily stored as twos-complement.

Comment: Signed integers are now required to use twos complement in C++20 (:

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the constructors of `std::bitset`. As you'll find out, it has no constructor accepting a signed integer. The only integral constructor is the one accepting an `unsigned long`.

So, when you pass an integer, it is first converted to unsigned. What happens, is the converted value will be a positive value, same as the signed one modulo the maximum value of the unsigned type.